# How to fetch and display different user data from array of users stored in Core data in tableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, tableview

I have an array of names and addresses of users as :-

```
multipleUsersName = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"user 1", @"user 2", @"user 3", @"user 4",nil];
userAddresses=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Dehradun",@"Tripura",@"Kolkata",@"Meghalaya ",nil];
```

I am saving these data in `CoreData`. In the `CoreData` table, userAddress and userName are the entities. Now I want to show the details in table view as :-

In the first cell, only USER 1 details and in the second cell only USER 2 details regardless how many times I save the record.
So, anyone can tell me how to fetch different user's records ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use the below code

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityNameStr)
        fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType;
        fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true; // This will return Distinct user details
        fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch =  attributes as [AnyObject];//NSArray(object: attributeName)
```

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code it return all Records in your table.

```
 -(NSMutableArray *)GetAllRecods
    {

            id context = [[CoreDataDAL sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];  //get your managedObjectContext here i am useing  core data singleton class

            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@“YourTableName”];
            NSMutableArray *Project = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];

            return Project;
      }
```

you can access records  in uitableview like this.

```
yourtablename *ob = [arrayorRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: different user record in different cell of tableview ?

Comment: this method return all records of your table in array. you can use this array in your table view.